# Loading data to Chain of Spinners according to the previous selected value

Tags: android, json, android-spinner

I have 3 spinners in my activity and I'm loading data for these 3 spinners from json response.

1st spinner(crustSP) gets data straight forward from the json response.
2nd spinner's (SizeSP) data depends on what selected from 1st spinner and
3rd spinner's (extraDescriptionOneSP) data depends on what select from 2nd spinner.

My question is it crashes inside 2nd SP because I haven't selected any value inside that when activity starting (I have shown that inside the code as a comment), how can I overcome that? where should I have that piece of code. It goes on without crashing when I hard code the position of sizeSp.

```
crust = Utils.removeDuplicatesFromList(crust);
            ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapterCru = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                    this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, crust);
            dataAdapterCru
                    .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            crustSP.setAdapter(dataAdapterCru);

            crustSP.setOnItemSelectedListener(new MyOnItemSelectedListener(
                    ActivityPizzaCustomize.this) {

                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,
                        View view, int position, long id) {

                    String crustSelectedItem = crustSP.getSelectedItem()
                            .toString();

                    List<String> resultDescription = getFilteredDescriptions(
                            crustSelectedItem, sizeDescription);
                    sizeSP.setOnItemSelectedListener(new MyOnItemSelectedListener(
                            ActivityPizzaCustomize.this) {

                        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,
                                View view, int position, long id) {

                            String sizeSelectedItem = sizeSP
                                    .getSelectedItem().toString(); // it crashes here since I haven't selected any value

                            List<String> resultTopping = getFilteredToppings(
                                    sizeSelectedItem, topDescription);

                            extraDescriptionOneSP
                                    .setOnItemSelectedListener(new MyOnItemSelectedListener(
                                            ActivityPizzaCustomize.this));
                            ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapterExtraDesOne = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                                    ActivityPizzaCustomize.this,
                                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
                                    resultTopping);
                            dataAdapterExtraDesOne
                                    .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                            extraDescriptionOneSP
                                    .setAdapter(dataAdapterExtraDesOne);
                            extraDescriptionOneSP
                                    .setAdapter(new NothingSelectedSpinnerAdapter(
                                            dataAdapterExtraDesOne,
                                            R.layout.contact_spinner_row_nothing_selected,
                                            ActivityPizzaCustomize.this));
                        }

                    });

                    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapterDes = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                            ActivityPizzaCustomize.this,
                            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
                            resultDescription);
                    dataAdapterDes
                            .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                    sizeSP.setAdapter(dataAdapterDes);
                    sizeSP.setAdapter(new NothingSelectedSpinnerAdapter(
                            dataAdapterDes,
                            R.layout.contact_spinner_row_nothing_selected,
                            ActivityPizzaCustomize.this));
                }
            });
```

This is how I filter the items,

```
List<String> getFilteredDescriptions(String crustSelectedItem,
            List<String> sizeDescription) {
        List<String> resultDescription = new ArrayList<String>();
        crustSelectedItem = crustSP.getSelectedItem().toString();

        if (sizeDescription == null || sizeDescription.isEmpty())
            return resultDescription;

        for (int i = 0; i < sizeDescription.size(); i++) {
            sizeDescription = Utils.removeDuplicatesFromList(sizeDescription);
            if (!sizeDescription.get(i).contains(crustSelectedItem))
                continue;

            resultDescription.add(sizeDescription.get(i));
        }

        return resultDescription;
    }

    List<String> getFilteredToppings(String sizeSelectedItem,
            List<String> topDescription) {
        List<String> resultTopping = new ArrayList<String>();
        sizeSelectedItem = sizeSP.getSelectedItem().toString();

        if (topDescription == null || topDescription.isEmpty())
            return resultTopping;

        for (int i = 0; i < topDescription.size(); i++) {
            topDescription = Utils.removeDuplicatesFromList(topDescription);
            if (!topDescription.get(i).contains(sizeSelectedItem))
                continue;

            resultTopping.add(topDescription.get(i));
        }

        return resultTopping;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to call onItemSelectedListner inside the other one, Like,,

```
    spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int position, long id) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                         Arraylist2.add((String)spinner1.getItemAtPosition(position));

//Some Code/Ligic here
                    spinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,
                                View view, int position2, long id) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            Arraylist3.add((String) spinner2.getItemAtPosition(position2));

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub111

                        }
                    });

                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
            });
```

Hope it helps...

Comment: I can't figure whats the difference between ur code and mine. can u spot the difrence. please tell me if u can

Comment: Sorry, I tried it right now.. Its working fine for me.. Can you provide logcat error..? What nature of error you are getting..?

Answer (score 0):

just give it try..
put this code before setting onItemSelectedListner..

```
spin1.setSelection(0, false);
```